# How to override iOS App lifecycle in Flutter plugin

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

On the Swift end of my flutter plugin, I needed to override `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationWillResignActive` but I don't know how to go about this.

Assuming it is just a plain flutter app, I would have done this in **AppDelegate**:

```
   override func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        
    }
    
    override func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        
    }
```

But that doesn't appear to be working on the plugin class.

Please, note that I am aware that I can do this using [AppLifecycleState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState.html) on the Flutter end, but like I said it is important that I do this on the Swift end

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement the `FlutterApplicationLifeCycleDelegate` interface and register it using `register` method on your `FlutterPlugin` class.

OBS: `FlutterPlugin` class has already inherinted `FlutterApplicationLifeCycleDelegate` interface, so you don't need to worry about it

**Step 1**: register your pluggin as an `ApplicationDelegate` class:

```
public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "my_wonderful_plugin_id", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
    let instance = MyWonderfulPlugin() // YOUR PLUGGIN NAME INSTEAD

    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
    registrar.addApplicationDelegate(instance) // THIS IS THE BIG SECRET
}
```

**Step 2**: Implement the interface, including the methods bellow on your plugin class:

```
public func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    debugPrint("applicationDidBecomeActive")
}

public func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    debugPrint("applicationWillTerminate")
}

public func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    debugPrint("applicationWillResignActive")
}

public func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    debugPrint("applicationDidEnterBackground")
}

public func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("applicationWillEnterForeground")
}
```

Thats it! Yahoooow!

Comment: thanks, but I believe it should be used like this then: `registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)`
`registrar.addApplicationDelegate(instance)`